# Change another input field with ajax callback

Tags: forms, ajax

I have an existing node with text fields. I want to change another field with ajax; if I input text in text field I need this text appears in another text field. I implemented `hook_form_alter()` with #ajax callback and it works fine, but when I delete this text and write another value in the same field, the  other field is not changing with #ajax_callback. I guess my ajax callback runs only one time.

Please check my code below.

```
    function classes_payment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
    {


        if ($form_id == 'payment_node_form') {
            //dsm($form);
            $form['#validate'][] = 'classes_payment_form_validate';
            dpm($form['#validate']);


            $form['field_test1']['und'][0]['value']['#ajax'] = array(
                'event' => 'change',
                'callback' => 'validate_uid_ajax_callback',
                'wrapper' => 'field-test2-add-more-wrapper',
                'method' => 'replace',
                'effect' => 'fade',


            );
            $form['field_test2']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'xyz';

            $father_name = $form_state['values']['field_father_name']['und'][0]['value'];

            if (!empty($form_state['values']['field_test1']['und'][0]['value'])) {
                $test1_value = $form_state['values']['field_test1']['und'][0]['value'];
                $form['field_test2']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] = $test1_value;
            } elseif (!empty($form_state['values']['field_test2']['und'][0]['value'])) {
                $form_state['values']['field_test2']['und'][0]['value'] = $test1_value;
            }

        }
    }

    function validate_uid_ajax_callback(&$form, &$form_state)
    {
        return $form["field_test2"];

    }

    function classes_payment_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
    {

    dpm($form_state);

       }
```